# Drawing a line in a Bitmap using X and Y coordinates

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a transparent bitmap containing a thin line only. I've extracted the X,Y coordinates using `TBitmapData` in Delphi FMX. I have the X and Y coordinates of each pixel of the line in the Bitmap.  My question is how to Draw again the same line in that Bitmap using the X,Y coordinates with a different color  ?  Or perhaps plotting it in an empty Bitmap

Comment: Have a look at [`TBitmap.Canvas.DrawLine()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawLine) or [`TBitmap.Canvas.DrawPath()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawPath). Both methods use the [`TBitmap.Canvas.Stroke`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.Stroke) for the color and pattern of the lines.

Comment: Yes that would help. I can create multiple lines, each 2 XY lines corresponds to start and end point of the line. @RemyLebeau